# How can I force the Nautilus sidebar text color to stay white in my Ambiance modification?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, themes, customization, text

This is related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/78653/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-this-part-of-nautilus-for-my-ambiance-theme-modifi/79006#79006, which has just been solved. Now I have a new issue.

As shown below, the text color for the sidebar does not want to stay white unless it is selected. It did earlier, but now it's not and I'm not sure why.

[image: Screenshot of Nautilus with modified theme and disappearing text]

How can I force that text to stay white in the theme files? (See the linked question above for a reference as to what changes I made; everything else is the same as regular Ambiance.)

**Note:** it'd be great if the white used for the sidebar text color was the same as the default white used for the active window titlebar text; `#ffffff` might be a little too bright, and I'm trying to stay close to the original look of Ambiance.

Comment: As I noted in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1783/dark-sidebar-for-nautilus-in-11-10), I may have a solution to this, but I want to wait a bit first and test it to make sure it's a proper fix first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it now. In `Ambiance Dark Sidebar/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css`, add this line inside the **sidebar** section:

```
color: @dark_fg_color;
```